# Measuring visitor HTTP cache hit ratio for external CDN resources

Tags: javascript, http, cdn

My site uses several common CDN hosted resources, like `bootstrap.css`,  `jquery.js` and `fontawesome.css`. Is it possible to get information, probably with JavaScript, do my site visitors have warm caches for these resources in their web browsers?

Comment: I suppose you could measure load times, but that would be flaky at best. I'm not aware of any "standard" solution to query a specific browser's cache state. Add-ons may have access to that information, though.

Comment: Take jQuery specifically.  Could you do a `var isLoaded = (jQuery) ? true : false;` and then load the library off the CDN if needed, in that conditional block then also load a pixel / make an xhr request to your server?  Is the idea just to measure this for a while?

Comment: Related: http://www.sitepoint.com/mozilla-to-tackle-browser-css-history-privacy-leak/

Answer (score 2):

While not an answer, some interesting insight I found when working on this problem with **Chrome**:

Fetching the resource from CDN is a deferred call, while fetching an item from the cache seems in fact to be a blocking call, despite being quite fast.
Firefox didn't seem to this exhibit behavior consistently (and I didn't even bother with IE).

To test this observation further, I built the following small fiddle, which works reliably for me **on Chrome**. Please leave a comment on your own test results if you have the time.

```js
var testSource = function(href) {
  var timeLimit = 5;
  var l = document.createElement("link");
  l.rel = "stylesheet";
  l.type = "text/css";
  l.href = href;
  var s1 = document.createElement("script");
  s1.innerHTML = "window.d = new Date();";
  var s2 = document.createElement("script");
  s2.innerHTML = "window.d2 = new Date();";
  document.head.appendChild(s1);
  document.head.appendChild(l);
  document.head.appendChild(s2);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      if (typeof(d2) === "undefined" || d2 - d > timeLimit) {
        p.innerHTML = "guess cache";
      } else {
        p.innerHTML = "guess load";
      }
      p.innerHTML += " (" + href + ")";
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    },
    timeLimit * 10);
}

btn.onclick = function() {
  testSource(inp.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" value="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="test url" />
```

Comment: Works on Chrome desktop, does not work Firefox, as you said. Hopefully similar mechanism can be found for all browsers.

Comment: This could be also considered as a privacy leak: http://www.sitepoint.com/mozilla-to-tackle-browser-css-history-privacy-leak/ so maybe check if this work for every resoucre or certain kind of URLs only?